# Change font for whole sections of a memoir

Tags: fonts, memoir

I am writing a book in the Memoir package. The book is, in fact, a memoir. Most of the book is fairly standard content, but some sections are not. I am calling these "interludes".  I now have them marked by having "Interlude" in the section name, which I am putting in the header of the page. But I was thinking of marking these sections by using a different font (maybe Times).

I was wondering a) If this is a good idea (although that may be off topic) and b) How to do this?

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I tried Googling and got very confused.

Thanks

Comment: The subjective question of whether to do this is off topic. But the how question is answerable. Easiest would probably to use the builtin sectioning hooks that `memoir` provides to change the font.

Comment: The general method for font changing can be found here: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249). If that's all you need, then this is a duplicate. If you're interested in doing it more automatically then make that the focus of your question and provide a MWE to show what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! The answer you hightlighted solved my problem, so this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If using `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` along with the `fontspec` package, do the following.

In the preamble, use the command `\newfontfamily` to define a command that will allow you to easily switch to the desired font, e.g.:

`\newfontfamily\interludefont[UprightFont={* Light},BoldFont={* Bold}]{AT Hadriano Std}`

This is a manual solution, though: at the beginning of each "interlude", you need to input your `\interludefont` command. For setting a specific style for the body of one particular type of section, however, I don't know.

Comment: This assumes the OP is using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, since this is a `fontspec` command. But they haven't provided any code so we don't know that.

Comment: Did with whatever little info we have. Anyway, only he can tell.